# How to center headings at KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

As a continue to this question: [customize subsubsection with koma script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353008/customize-subsubsection-with-koma-script)

How do I center the titles?

```
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    %\@tempswafalse
        \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
                \mbox{\@hangfrom{\underline{{#3}{#4}\adforn{12}}}}
        }
        {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
                \mbox{\@hangfrom{\underline{{#3}{#4}\adforn{24}}}}%
        }
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}}%
```

And here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec,adforn}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    %\@tempswafalse
        \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
                \mbox{\@hangfrom{\underline{{#3}{#4}\adforn{12}}}}
        }
        {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
                \mbox{\@hangfrom{\underline{{#3}{#4}\adforn{24}}}}%
        }
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{ABC}

\section{abc}

\subsection{def}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to center the section title and the subsection title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add `\centering` in your changed code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec,adforn}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    %\@tempswafalse
        \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
                \centering\mbox{\@hangfrom{\underline{{#3}{#4}\adforn{12}}}}
        }
        {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{%
                \centering\mbox{\@hangfrom{\underline{{#3}{#4}\adforn{24}}}}%
        }
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{ABC}

\section{abc}

\subsection{def}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

But to be honest why do you change the internal format of KOMA-Script? That is not a very good idea.  Better is the following (and please omit underlining in headings, use instead bold or italic):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec,adforn}


\begin{document}

\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}    % <==============================
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\centering} % <==============================

\part{ABC}

\section{abc test test test test test test test test test test test test 
  test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
  test test test test test test \adforn{12}} % <========================

\subsection{def \adforn{24}} % <========================================
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: better resulting]

In this way the centering is working for long section headings too, in the first variant it can not work!

Comment: Very nice....and thank you very much for your consideration on tags.

Comment: For your question: some time the document can much prettier when the titles are centered :-) BTW - If I want underlined text, this is possible?

Comment: BTW, about your second example - I want the `adforn` symbols will be part of the titles, i.e. - that every title they will be automatically, like the MWE that I posted - is this possible?

Comment: @heblyx well underlining is a problem in LaTeX, but see answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9552/16550 for that problem.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll check it later :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine `\raggedsection` to change the alignment of all headings set by `\sectionlinesformat`.

Underlining is only possible for oneline headings. So you can remove `\@hangfrom` for them.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{adforn}
\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}% center headings like \section, \subsection etc.

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{\hskip#2\underline{#3#4\adforn{12}}}%
    {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\hskip#2\underline{#3#4\adforn{24}}}
      {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}}%

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{abc}
\blindtext
\subsection{def}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

If there are also longer headings, remove the (ugly) underline.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{adforn}
\renewcommand\raggedsection{\centering}

\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4%
    \ifstr{#1}{section}{\adforn{12}}
      {\ifstr{#1}{subsection}{\adforn{24}}{}}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc}
\blindtext
\subsection{def}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]