# Centering parts at KOMA-Script

Tags: titles, koma-script

As a continue to this question: [How to center headings at KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479612/how-to-center-headings-at-koma-script)
I'm trying to center the parts...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adforn}

\setkomafont{part}{\itshape}
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{ #2 \centering{\adforn{36}\hbox{#3\adforn{64}}}}

\begin{document}
\part{ABC}
\end{document}
```

The example above don't work:
[image]

I want that ABC will be at the center (the second line), without using the `\hfill` command....

Do you know how can I do it?
And if I want that also the `Part I.` will be centered - how can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adforn}

\setkomafont{part}{\itshape}
\let\raggedpart\centering
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{#2\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\adforn{36}\hbox{#3\adforn{64}}}}%

\begin{document}

\part{ABC}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And if I want both lines will be centered (at `scrartcl` only the second line centered, at `scrbook` both centered, but I'm using `scrartcl` )? Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten you used `scrartcl`. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Thank you! But if I want that only the second line will be centered? This is possible?

Comment: You've observed it yourself: remove the line `\letraggedpart\centering`. If you code instead: `\let\raggedpart\raggedleft`, you'll have the first line flushright, and the second line centred.

Comment: Thank you!! Works!!