# adding subsubsection to Koma-script scrreprt

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

The Koma-script class `scrreprt` does not provide numbering of `\subsubsection`. I would like to have, if possible, `\subsubsection` available like `\subsection`. I have found [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353008/customize-subsubsection-with-koma-script) but the question is asking more advanced formatting which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the KOMA classes, the counter `secnumdepth` controls the level down to which the headings are numbered. The default for `scrreprt` is `\subsectionnumdepth`, i.e. `\subsection` is the lowest level that still gets a number, and all levels below don't. The solution is thus to set the value of `secnumdepth` to `\subsubsectionnumdepth`.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{The subsection}
\subsubsection{New subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Is is possible to add \subsubsubsection? I have tried the same idea but did not work.

Comment: @user1155710 see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356574/103046