# Modify subsection numbering in KOMA

Tags: koma-script, section-titles, scrartcl

In my `scrartcl`, I want to modify the subsection numbering as `UNIT I`, without being preceded by section numbering. How I can do that?

An MWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{World}

Instead of \textbf{1.1 World}, I want \textbf{Unit I. World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a chance that you'll need to cross-reference multiple subsections and would like the cross-reference to look like "... as discussed in Units II, III, and IV, ..."? Please advise.

Comment: @mico You overachiever! :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Your answer is fine. I believe I was the first one to upvote it. :-)

Comment: @BaRud Is your problem solved? If yes, then consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Comment: Oh... I upvoted your answer, missed to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *literally* googeled "koma latex change subsection" and used the [first hit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353008) :).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353008
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{Unit \Roman{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\subsection{World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your use case doesn't require you to create cross-references to the "units", [@Dr.ManuelKuehner's simple and straightforward answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580122/5001) is perfectly adequate.

In, however, if you foresee a need to create cross-references of the units, it's better *not* to incorporate the word "Unit" directly into the macro `\thesubsection`. Instead, it would be better to make use of the low-level LaTeX command `\@seccntformat`; see below for an implementation of this idea. If you pursue this approach, as an added bonus you can make use of the cross-referencing capabilities of the `cleveref` package, e.g., use a `\cref` or `\Cref` command to create a cross-referencing call-out to multiple objects in one go.

Incidentally, the `\@seccntformat` approach works equally well with the Koma-Script document classes and with the "basic" LaTeX document classes (`article`, `report` and `book`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
    {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
    {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{Unit \thesubsection\@.\space} % subsection level
\makeatother

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}

\usepackage{cleveref} % for \cref and \Cref macros
\crefname{subsection}{unit}{units} % label to be used in cross-references

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}       \label{sec:hello}
\subsection{World}    \label{sec:world}
\subsection{Solar System} \label{sec:system}
\subsection{Galaxy}   \label{sec:galaxy}
\subsection{Universe} \label{sec:universe}

As required, the first subsection header says \textbf{Unit I\@. World}.

\medskip
\noindent
As shown in \Cref{sec:world,sec:galaxy,sec:universe} of \Cref{sec:hello}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Amazing! Is "\@" something that should be familiar to a normal TeX user?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - The `\@` directive informs TeX that the following `.` particle should be treated as a sentence-ending punctuation mark. The use of `\@` is admittedly optional, but I thought it provides a nice aesthetic touch here, since it provides for just a little bit of visual "breathing space" between the uppercase-Roman numeral and the uppercase letter that starts off the section's text label. (Of course, if `\frenchspacing` is in effect, then `\@` has no effect, but it doesn't hurt either.)